# sum of list elements is equal to required number(sum)

Tags: python-3.x

want to write a program to find lowest number of integers in the array that sums up the given number. The program should ask user to input array of integers (“Input Array”) and the required sum (“Required Sum”). The output (“Output”) should list the lowest number of integers from the input array that sums up the “Required Sum”.  Refer to examples given below.

input Array : [10, 0, -1, 20, 25, 30]

Required Sum: 59
Output: [10, -1, 20, 30]

Required Sum: 60
Output: [10, 20, 30]

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: This is a variant of the so-called knapsack problem. It's hard to get the optimal solution when the size of the input array increases, so it's often approximated. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/ for a solution, but I encourage you to read more about it and of course to try solving it on your own.

Comment: thanx.!! mykola i'll try my best..to solve.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-minimum-number-of-coins-that-make-a-change/